# zeroshell qos global bandwidth maximum vs guaranteed

Tags: router, qos, bandwidth-control

When using [Zeroshell QoS](http://zeroshell.org/qos/) what is the difference between the maximum and guaranteed bandwidth when talking about the global bandwidth for the interface?

I understand the difference for each of the classes but how does the guaranteed value apply to the interface global bandwidth?

I've set up Zeroshell as a router at several work sites in remote areas that have poor internet speed/quality/consistency. Initially I thought that you put values in there based on what you could expect your actual available bandwidth to vary by. So for a site with 600-800 kbps actual available upload speed, if I set the guaranteed to 550 kbps and max to 700kbps I thought that's what it was for. But after some experimentation, the global guaranteed bandwidth seems to be only used for displaying the % values on the web gui. Also when the actual available bandwidth falls below the maximum setting then qos stops working properly even though the actual bandwidth is still higher than the guaranteed value.

Does anyone have more info on what the zeroshell setting for the interface global guaranteed bandwidth is for? On the documentation page I linked, it says to set it the same as the max. If it is always supposed to be the same, why have a separate setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it the same as the max.
The shell command (tc) is the same to define your global bandwidth for the interface, and to define a class, so it has a guaranteed-bandwidth parameter and a max-bandwidth parameter.

Although, I agree zeroshell could have remove one of the two values from GUI to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For those of us not intimately familiar with the tc command, does this make the interface guaranteed bandwidth parameter useless? I can attest that zeroshell and the underlying QoS system will accept different values for max and guaranteed. Though changing the guaranteed value seems to have no effect that I can tell, at least when it is equal or less than the max value.

Comment: Well, I don't know the formulas behind. I'd say that in the worst case, set an inferior value to the guaranteed-bandwidth will use more compute.